# MVVMLight ViewModel folder missing

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I am trying to install MVVMLight for my .NET Core application, but after finishing installing the ViewModel folder is not being generated. In the past I've worked with .NET Framework and MVVMLight, and it worked just fine. Does somebody know how I can fix it so the ViewModel folder and the MainViewModel.cs and the ViewModelLocator.cs will be generated?